# Getting a syntax error with SQL statement in VBA for Access and definitely has to do with single and double quotes and variables

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I've tried to wrap my head around the logic of how quotes work, but I cannot find any official documentation from Microsoft that really explains this in depth. I think the logic behind this code works but of course it doesn't.
Here's my logic:
The double quotes in front of UPDATE start the string and the double quotes behind Sector ends the string. Variables and strings must be separated by an ampersand. Done. Now I need to continue the string so I wrap WHERE ID to concatenate it to the variable, and rst!ID is not a string so it needs no quotes.  STILL WRONG.  Please help me understand where my logic is off here?  Note: test is a string variable.

Thank you!

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE MyTable SET MyField = 'Sector'" & test & "WHERE ID =" rst!ID
```

Comment: How does `test` play into things? You want to make sure there's a space before the `WHERE` in order for it to be parsable.

Comment: Test is a string variable that should follow behind Sector.  End result is something like "Sector: 33,22" (test = 33,22 and while they're numbers, the numbers are strings).

Comment: That returns a syntax error.

Comment: `= 'Sector:" & test & "' WHERE ID =" & rst!ID` - that puts the value of test inside the single quotes, and adds a space.  (forgot an ampersand)

Comment: I used the part of the code that I entered before the = sign, and typed what you wrote.  Still getting a syntax error.  The final code I'm trying to get is -- UPDATE MyTable SET MyField = 'Sector: 33,22' WHERE ID 4 = 4 to be a valid SQL statement, correct?

Comment: `WHERE ID 4 = 4` certainly doesn't look right.

Comment: Ok That worked!!! I'm going to look over what you typed, I don't care how long it takes to try to understand the logic.  Thank you!

Comment: I Don't understand why you added the single quote next to WHERE. *sigh* I wish there was full documentation on this somewhere. Nevermind, I think I get the logic behind it!

Comment: That single quote was meant to "close" the opening one once you included the variable - and the space needs to be there so the parser knows you are starting the WHERE part. Notice i removed one of the single quotes from `Sector`

Comment: OK Makes perfect sense, thank you so much!!!

Comment: Make sure parens, quotes, apostrophes, brackets are always in pairs.

Comment: I will definitely do that.  You're a lifesaver.  I can finally finish this project and go to sleep.  Seriously, thank you.

Comment: When using any kind of dynamic command concoction the first step is to print the string out and inspect it

Answer (score 1):

that should be

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE MyTable SET MyField = 'Sector" & test & "' WHERE ID =" rst!ID
```

First the ' needs to go behind "test", second there is a space necessary before "where".

Answer (score 0):

1. Your whole String value needs to be into single quote like this:
   ...." MyField = 'Sector" & test & "' ...."
2. You should also be careful about spaces before and after double quotes because it will give you syntax errors in your sql statement.
3. When you call your table in vba access maybe you need to put your table name into brackets (at least in my code this was a problem)

So, I would write it like this:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE [MyTable] a  SET [MyField] = 'Sector" & test & "' WHERE a.[ID] ="& rst!ID
```

You could also print the command before execution just to see what is the problem, sometimes it helps a lot.
So I would recommend you to run this at first, without then RunSQL command:

```
MsgBox "UPDATE [MyTable] a  SET [MyField] = 'Sector" & test & "' WHERE a.[ID] ="& rst!ID
```

and make changes of the wrong parts.